# Salt Water Damaged iPhone, Can I get the content off it?

Tags: iphone, damage

My iPhone X keeps showing the Apple Logo, then cuts out and does the same. I have got a lot of photos on in that I would like to get off. Would that be possible?

Any software, or other methods to get the content off a dead iphone?

Comment: See [iPad Rehab](https://www.ipadrehab.com/article.cfm?ArticleNumber=29) for a company that specializes in data recovery for these exact scenarios

Comment: If you decide it's not worth it to get professional data recovery services, you could try opening it up, **removing the battery**, and washing it thoroughly with everclear 190, then letting it dry for a week or two. It might revive when you plug in a new battery then. Obviously this is a last resort method.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is called a boot loop.  It is caused by any number of things, but based on your description, it sounds like it was caused by physical damage.

Can this be recovered?

Yes, but there’s no software that gets around a physical problem.   For this type of issue, it’s possible that restoring your phone from a backup you may be able to “fix” the problem.  However, any data not backed up can and will be lost.

There are 3rd party services that offer recovery services - [iPad Rehab](https://www.ipadrehab.com/article.cfm?ArticleNumber=29) is one such example.  They are a bit pricy, but on the flip side, they don’t charge you unless they’re successful. (I’m not affiliated, just very familiar with their offerings)

Answer (score 0):

yah boot loops can be a real pain. Salt water damaged iPhones can have a few walls to hop over in order to get the data recovered. The main problem is encryption, a few companies can recover files directly from the NAND flash. It really depends on if the phone version is encrypted and how the smartphone is damaged.

Many people do not have a backup, in this case, if the lost data is important you will want to recover it I am sure. In this case just get the phone to a smartphone recovery company as soon as possible. The longer you wait the more damage will take place due to corrosion. [eProvided](https://www.eprovided.com/data-recovery-blog/recover-data-salt-water-damage/) is a place I would speak with.